# Generate 12 (perceptually) uniformly-spaced colours using d3

Tags: d3.js, color-space, hsl

This question follows from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589186/generating-a-perceptually-accurate-colour-wheel-in-javascript

I'm trying to create 12 colours that are roughly uniformly spaced from one another perceptually.

d3  provides HSL, so `d3.hsl( (i/12)*360, 0.5, 0.5 )`

However, this doesn't work very well for greeny-yellowy colours.

d3 appears to provide HCL and LAB, but I can't see how to use these.

Is there any mathematical approach I can use, or should I just implement my own HSL hue transfer function?

Comment: IMHO this question should not be downvoted or closed (to whoever did that). It's a legitimate question about LAB color space, which lacks documentation on the d3 API reference.

Comment: This is likely to be tricky.  I definitely look into [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/)

Comment: I'd suggest you to use this library: https://vis4.net/blog/posts/mastering-multi-hued-color-scales/

 also you can have a look here: http://gka.github.io/palettes/#diverging|c0=darkred,deeppink,lightyellow|c1=lightyellow,lightgreen,teal|steps=13|bez0=1|bez1=1|coL0=1|coL1=1

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with d3, but assume it uses the typical CIELab convention which is `L: 0::255, a: -100::100, b: -100::100`

You can try

```
d3.lab( 128, 100 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i/12), 100 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i/12) )
```

This should create a visually uniform color wheel